# Select everything in a database that == something OR something else

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to select everything in a table where a column == "something" OR "somethingelse".

Is there a way of doing this without using raw SQL? Something like the following would be ideal.

```
Table.where(:col => "something" OR "somethingelse")
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to do this without using raw SQL? Are you attempting to write a query without the SELECT and FROM clauses? That would not make any sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Table.where(:col => ["something", "somethingelse"])
```

should generate

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN ('something', 'somethingelse')
```

Comment: Ugly version: `MyModel.where(my_model[:col].eq('something').or(my_model[:col].eq('somethingelse')))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
MyModel.where("col1 = ? or col1 = ?", "something","somethingelse")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the statement like this:

```
select * from table_name where column_name = value1 or column_name = value_2
```

You can also use:

```
select * from table_name where column_name in (value1,value2)
```